# client to client socket communication

Tags: c++, c, sockets, pthreads

I have a client/server program that allows multiple clients to be served via spawned threads from the server.  Currently the program just communicates with the server, however I am now wanting to redesign the program so that a client can establish communication with another client.
In terms of designing this I do not have too much experience to know what the right direction is.  Initially I thought about communication via the server threads, however I am not sure how to  notify the client of that thread that another client wants to establish communication.

For example I want to communicate from cli A to cli N:

```
Cli A <---> SerThread A <------> Main Thread <------> SerThread N <---> Cli N
```

I am not sure how Cli N can be informed that Cli A needs to communicate with it.

Until the Client reads from the socket it will not know that another client wants to communicate with it.  So if Cli N is in a state where it is waiting on user input until it does a send/receive it won't know.
I need a way to immediately inform the client that communication is waiting for it.

The more I think about the more I become confused, so I probably need some guidance before I properly try to design this.

Comment: Are the clients still connecting to the server first? can't the server tell the clients the information about the other clients?

Comment: Yes but what about a situation where the client has not done receive on the socket for example waiting on user input to do send/receive.  The client would only be notified once it does send/receive and that is up the user.  Is there a way to instantly inform the client?  Do I have to create another socket connection just for this?

Comment: The client should always be blocking in recv() (or, more likely in select() or poll() or some equivalent function that will return whenever the bytes are available to receive from the server).  Once that is done, all the server has to do is sent the appropriate bytes to the client and that will be sufficient to wake the client up and have it handle the bytes.

Comment: you shouldn't wait for user input before doing send/receive.. the UI thread and the "socket thread" should be separate.

Comment: Yea, I believe a separate thread on the client side would be best.  Thank you for all the info, I was confusing myself and now realize it's not that difficult to work this around.

Comment: How did you end up implementing this? I have the exact same situation right now, (only with C instead of C++). It's been a long time since this question so at this point you had already figured out or given up.

Answer (score 0):

Well,you can make it work like the switch :)
I assume that you want to establish connection between 2 clients via the server right?
If so,what you need to do is to give each client a serial number.
Then send a "request" from a client to the server with the information of the client you are searching for. Meaning a packet with the serial number.
The Server then can brodcast the information to the list of connected clients.
On the client side the client will receive the serial number thanks to the server.
If the serial number that the client received matches its own serial,the client will return true to the server. If not it will send out false.
Then,the next time there will be a search for that client,the server will already know where it is and it will send the messages solely to that specific client.
If the client disconnects obviously the serial number will then be erased and the server will lose the data regarding that client.

Comment: Yes the server can send the message but my problem is when the server notifies the client and the client has not initiated a receive on the socket (waiting on user input) how can I notify the client then?  The only thing I can think about is creating secondary connection on each client to receive requests from other clients.  But I am not sure if there is a better method to deal with this.

Answer (score 0):

i highly recommend you to read the [Beej's Guide to Network](http://www2.engr.arizona.edu/~prakash/reference/socket.pdf), which is the bible of socket programming for begginers. You have a lot of examples there, and explains every function step by step, so you'll be able to understand everything if you take some time. The guide also includes a working example for a client-server connection which you can look actually for the problem that you have.
I learned this kind of stuff by reading this guide! I hope it helps! =)